# Ways to upload files from javaScript Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, wcf, cordova

I am developing an Android application using phonegap and I need to know how upload a file (images and videos) through JavaScript.

Can anybody help me with this?, give me any idea or something..

The application consume WCF Rest web services.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the filetransfer API - http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer should do the trick :)

Edit - 
To use the filetransfer you would do something like this..

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="photo";
options.fileName=fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

var params = new Object();
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";

options.params = params;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURI, "http://some.server.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
```

Make sure you're defining the fileURI. On your server you would be looking for a post with a name of "photo" or what ever you call the fileKey.

Comment: But which parameters pass to the server?